# How to use multiple wheel picker on React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, picker

I want to use multiple wheel Picker like this lib.

https://github.com/beefe/react-native-picker

But, all such libs use `react-native link`.

Is there any solutions?

Comment: can't understand what you want? `react-native link` link all library which you have added into your package. you should fire command `react-native link libraryname` to link specific library. `react-native link` add code multiple time into android. So try to avoid generic command and link specific library. you should use `react-native link react-native-picker` command.

Comment: Sorry, I want to use in Expo app, so I can't use `react-native link`.

Comment: as a side note https://github.com/beefe/react-native-picker/tree/pure-javascript-version link does not require `react-native link`

Answer (score 3):

You are right about react-native-picker. It uses native libraries, so you can't use it with expo.io.

What you can do, though, is to create a function(or module, or component) that, given an array of arrays, it will render pickers side to side. This will create the effect of a one-multi-wheel picker.

Here is an example of the idea.

```js
const Pickers = {
  /**
 * data: Array of Arrays. Each inner array will contains the values for each picker i.e: [[1,2,3],[:], [1,2,3,4]]
 * preselectedValue: Array with value for each column i.e: [2, :, 2]
 * confirmFunction: the function that you will do something with the alternated values in picker.
 */
  multiColumnPicker: (data, preselectedValue, confirmFunction) => {
    let _bindArray = preselectedValue;

    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row'
      }}>{/* Use FLEX to position columns side-by-side*/}

        {data.map((column, columnIndex) => {
          {/* Iterate data. For each inner array we create a <Picker> */}
          {/*note: indexOf works only with the same type of elements. So, ensure that the element you are looking for
            has the same type inside the array. In this example I wanted a String.*/}
          let _innerIndex = column.indexOf('' + _bindArray[columnIndex]);
          {/* Return the <Picker>. onValueChange we handle the changes accordingly and call the confirmation function. */}
          return <Picker
            key={columnIndex}
            selectedValue={column[_innerIndex]}
            style={{
            flex: 1
          }}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
            _innerIndex = itemIndex;
            _bindArray[columnIndex] = itemValue;
            confirmFunction(_bindArray);
          }}>
            {/* Creates the list of options */}
            {column.map((item, idx) => <Picker.Item key={idx} label={item} value={item}/>)}
          </Picker>
        })}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = Pickers;
```

Then in your View component inside render() add 
{Pickers.multiColumnPicker:(data, preselectedValue, confirmFunction)}

Hope that it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a pure JavaScript implementation of the iOS Wheel Picker that works with Expo.

It's called `react-native-segmented-picker`, and you can get it from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-segmented-picker